# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Testing in JMETER JDBC connection configuration

Tags: jmeter

I am configuring JDBC Connection in jmeter 2.8. I am using MySQL database. And also placed `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` in jmeter `/lib` directory.

Problem is when i run the sampler it gives a message

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Testing

in Response data tab in Results Tree. I am using Ubuntu OS. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 4):

1. First of all I would recommend switching to the latest available JMeter version which is [2.13](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as for now as newer version will have a number defects fixed including performance upgrades.
2. Second. Make sure that you have [MySQL JDBC Driver aka Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in JMeter's classpath. If you don't - download it, unpack and drop `mysql-connector-java-x.xx.xx-bin.jar` to JMeter's /lib folder. JMeter restart will be required to pick the library up
3. Third. Make sure that you provide correct "JDBC Driver Class" in [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration). It should be

   ```
   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   ```
4. See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guide for more details on how to setup JMeter for database load testing.
5. Finally. Looking into "localhost" in your JDBC URL, it is not recommended to have load generator (JMeter) and application under test (MySQL) on the same machine, if there is a possibility - use different machines for JMeter and the database to keep results clean as JMeter can consume resources and impact MySQL performance and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The point 2 is essential here:

"Second. Make sure that you have MySQL JDBC Driver aka Connector/J in JMeter's classpath. If you don't - download it, unpack and drop mysql-connector-java-x.xx.xx-bin.jar to JMeter's /lib folder. JMeter restart will be required to pick the library up"

Please be sure that .jar file is added directly to the lib folder.